# The toolbar hides no matter which RecyclerView scrolls

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I have in layout normal a RecyclerView and in my BottomSheet and the toolbar also hides when the RecyclerView in my BottomSheet scrolls, even if it doesn't have the `app:layout_behavior` attribute. How can I solve this problem?

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android/white"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        app:elevation="0dp">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/titleTextView"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                android:text="Title"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="30sp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"

                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior">

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/itemRecyclerView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="90dp"
            android:fastScrollEnabled="true"
            android:overScrollMode="never"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    </FrameLayout>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottomSheet"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"

        app:behavior_hideable="false"
        app:behavior_peekHeight="88dp"

        app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetBehavior">

        <View
            android:id="@+id/bottomSheetShadow"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="4dp"
            android:background="@drawable/bottom_sheet_shadow"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/bottomSheetLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/bottomSheetShadow">

            <View
                android:id="@+id/bottomSheetSliderView"
                android:layout_width="24dp"
                android:layout_height="4dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:background="@drawable/bottom_sheet_slider"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/bottomSheetTitleTextView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="42dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                android:text="BottomSheetTitle"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="30sp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"

                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/bottomSheetSliderView" />

            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/navRecyclerView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
                android:overScrollMode="never"
                app:elevation="0dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHeight_default="wrap"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/bottomSheetTitleTextView" />
        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

Please use the third flag - snap, to layout_scrollFlags property. It will fix your issue.

```
  <Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:elevation="5dp"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|snap" />
```

This option will determine what to do when a view only has been partially reduced. If scrolling ends and the view size has been reduced to less than 50% of its original, then this view to return to its original size. If the size is greater than 50% of its size, it will disappear completely.

Answer (score 1):

```
AppBarLayout.LayoutParams params = (AppBarLayout.LayoutParams) toolbar.getLayoutParams();
params.setScrollFlags(0);
```

not sure, maybe helps :) if  not please share your xml

Comment: I added my XML code. It doesn't matter whether I use the ```RecyclerView```, which is not in the ```BottomSheet``` or the in the ```BottomSheet```, my ```AppBarLayout``` hides always.